# Use the orthonormality of $u,v,w$ to write the following vectors as linear combinations of $u,v$ and $w$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products, orthonormal

Let $V$ be the vector space $\mathbb R^3$ with inner product $$(v,w)=3(v_1w_1)-2(v_1w_2)-2(v_2w_1)+5(v_2w_2)-3(v_2w_3)-3(v_3w_2)+3(v_3w_3)$$

where $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and $w=(w_1,w_2,w_3)$.

#### Part 1

Prove that the vectors $u=(1,1,1)$, $v=(0,1/2,(\sqrt{6}-2/2\sqrt{6})$, $w=(0,1/2,3+\sqrt{6}/6)$ are orthonormal in $V$.

#### Part 2

Use the orthonormality of $u,v,w$ to write the following vectors as linear combinations of $u,v$, and $w$:  $$(1,2,3),\ (1,0,0), \ (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$$

I understand part 1 but how do I do part 2?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference